# How to make it so UI has bootstrap 4 tabs which do a post on each button click?

Tags: bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using bootstrap 4 with bearer token in asp.net core 2.2. I would like to create tabs so the user can navigate better. Where do I start? I looked at my coworkers code and he only has one post method on the entire form. Is there some way to send data to database every time I click the post  request.

I have tried putting only the following section of my coworkers code into my cshtml page. 
'''

```
<div id="pills" class='wizardpills'>
        <ul class="form-wizard">
            <li><a href="#pills-tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span>Basics</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pills-tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span>Profile</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pills-tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pills-tab4" data-toggle="tab"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#pills-tab5" data-toggle="tab"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="bar" class="progress active">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary " role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
'''

My code looks like the following:
_NewDesign.cshtml(shared layout page)
'''
@using PhillipCapital.Entity.DataObjects

@{
    //int length = menu.Count;

}

<html5>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/4.4.8/collection/icon/icon.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        @*<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/css/newdesign.css">*@
        <script src="~/js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="~/js/ApplicantType.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intl-tel-input/12.1.2/css/intlTelInput.css">
    </head>

    <style>
        .advanceBar {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #eaf0f4;
            height: 10px;
            padding-top: 25px;
        }

        .milestone {
            float: left;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            transform: translateY(-30px);
        }

            .milestone .content {
                height: 50px;
                width: 50px;
                border-radius: 25px;
            }

            .milestone .barBackground {
                height: 10px;
                transform: translateY(30px);
            }

        .advance {
            float: left;
            height: 10px;
        }

        .active {
            background-color: #5cb85c;
        }

        .inactive {
            background-color: #eaf0f4;
        }

        .active .fa {
            color: white;
            transform: translateY(15px);
        }

        .inactive .fa {
            color: #99a2a8;
            transform: translateY(15px);
        }
    </style>

    <body>

        <!--<section class="multi_step_form">
    <div class="advanceBar" id="advanceBar">
        <div class="advance active" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="milestone">
            <div class="barBackground active">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="content active"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i></div>
        </div>

        <div class="advance active" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="advance active" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="milestone">
            <div class="barBackground active">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="content active"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="advance active" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="advance active" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="milestone">
            <div class="barBackground inactive">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="content inactive"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i></div>
        </div>
        <div class="advance inactive" style="width:15%;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <!--<form id="msform">
        <!-- Tittle
        <div class="title">
            <h2>Verification Process</h2>
            <p>In order to use this service, you have to complete this verification process</p>
        </div>
        <!-- progressbar
        <ul id="progressbar">

        </ul>

    </form>-->
        <!--</section>-->
        <div id="pills" class='wizardpills'>
            <ul class="form-wizard">
                <li><a href="#pills-tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span>Basics</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#pills-tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span>Profile</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#pills-tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span>Contact</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#pills-tab4" data-toggle="tab"><span>Settings</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#pills-tab5" data-toggle="tab"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="bar" class="progress active">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary " role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html5>
```

I am trying to get the menu to work so that user can navigate to different pages but after submit which is like page 10 the user cannot come back. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch the click event on the tab, and do a form post via AJAX. However, that really only solves part of your problem. Server-side, you'd need to persist the partial form data in some way, most likely via `TempData`.

However, a tab-based form is generally better handled entirely client-side until you're ready to submit all the data. Employ client-side validation to ensure that each section is complete and valid before allowing the user to switch to the next tab. You can also employ `localStorage` to save each step as the user progresses. This will allow them to even leave and come back later to continue filling out the form. Just remember to clear out `localStorage` on final submission, so the data does not persist forever.

You still need server-side validation, because client-side validation can be incomplete or even tampered with. That also means the user could need to be sent back to the form again, after post. You can automatically change to the tab with errors via something like the following on page load:

```
var tab = $('.field-validation-invalid').eq(0).closest('.tab-pane').attr('id');
$('#' + tab).tab('show');
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without ajax? We are trying to make our site as secure as possible. Thats why we want to use httpclient.

Comment: There's nothing inherently "insecure" about AJAX. It's all in how you use it, just like anything else. Not sure what you're talking about with wanting to use `HttpClient`. That's exclusively server-side, so it doesn't really come into play here. Regardless, you can just as easily make insecure requests with `HttpClient`.